# Unable to import airflow providers package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am unable to import airflow providers package for Google. Command I used was

```
pip3 install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google
```

And it gives me the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-airflow-backport-providers-google (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for apache-airflow-backport-providers-google
```

Due to which my DAG is stuck and the error message is

```
Broken DAGS: No module named 'airflow.providers'
```

I checked in the airflow library: `env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow`

Can't find the providers folder.

**EDIT:** The above issue is solved when I upgraded the python version to 3.6+ as suggested in the answer. But now, facing a new value error issue.
I am using `DataprocInstantiateWorkflowTemplateOperator` after importing `airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc`.

Please find the error traceback below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workflow_dag.py", line 6, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocInstantiateWorkflowTemplateOperator
  File "/home/kshitij/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 36, in <module>
    from google.cloud.dataproc_v1beta2.types import (  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
  File "/home/kshitij/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .services.autoscaling_policy_service import AutoscalingPolicyServiceClient
  File "/home/kshitij/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/services/autoscaling_policy_service/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .client import AutoscalingPolicyServiceClient
  File "/home/kshitij/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/services/autoscaling_policy_service/client.py", line 33, in <module>
    from google.cloud.dataproc_v1beta2.services.autoscaling_policy_service import pagers
  File "/home/kshitij/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/services/autoscaling_policy_service/pagers.py", line 20, in <module>
    from google.cloud.dataproc_v1beta2.types import autoscaling_policies
  File "/home/kshitij/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/types/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .autoscaling_policies import (
  File "/home/kshitij/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/types/autoscaling_policies.py", line 41, in <module>
    class AutoscalingPolicy(proto.Message):
  File "/home/kshitij/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 139, in __new__
    field.descriptor.oneof_index = oneofs[field.oneof]
  File "/home/kshitij/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/proto/fields.py", line 113, in descriptor
    proto3_optional=self.optional,
ValueError: Protocol message FieldDescriptorProto has no "proto3_optional" field.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Python version is python3.5 and prior to it (see the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/) and the image below), you need to upgrade python to 3.6+ if you want to use the apache-airflow-backport-providers-google package.

[image]

Python 3.6 is supported by [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/python-version#how_versioning_works) and you could try either [upgrade your enviroment](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading) or create a new one.

Comment: I upgraded the python version and now facing a unique valueError issue.
`ValueError: Protocol message FieldDescriptorProto has no "proto3_optional" field.`

Adding the error traceback in the question itself. Please review it.

Comment: If the initial question was already answered, it would be better to open a new question with the traceback on the edit and a sample script of the new error, this should be easy to follow up. Feel free to post a link to this new question, so that I can help.